# Content asistant of eclipse is opening but description no

Tags: java, eclipse

i am using eclipse KEPLER 64 bit for windows 7 ,when i am pressing Ctr l+space the content assistant will appear but when i am clicking on each of them the description will not appear,i checked everything even in preferences>>  Java tab ,but really doesn't work yet..
additional info can not be find!!!

Comment: Does the problem persist if you use a new, fresh workspace?

Comment: yes,still the same even after deleting & downloading again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find how to fix this problem,after several hours challenge with the menus of Eclipse,
Window>>Preferences>>Java>>Editor>>Content Assist>>Advanced>>Check Java Proposal
& Window>>Preferences>>Java>>Editor>>Content Assist>>Folding>>>Check Comments & Header Comments & Imports,
the problem will be solved ....
that's it!!!